# speech terminology

Tags: speech

I was in a large group of friends and
My friend said, "Big Bear is the best place on Earth."
I responded, "to go skiing."

My intention was to specify that when she said "the best place on Earth" she was referring to "to go skiing." I was not agreeing with her, however I was being a bit rude by adding words to her mouth or shaping what she was saying because I knew that she did not think Big Bear was the best place on Earth in a general sense. Therefore, I wanted to specify her statement, so that the other people in the group who were listening would understand that she was referring to "the best place on Earth [to go skiing]."

What is it called when someone does this to another person's speech so that listeners would understand the person's speech better? Was my intention clear or would the other people listening assume that I felt that Big Bear was the best place on Earth to go skiing? I do not feel this way at all and I did not want listeners to assume that I think that "Big Bear is the best place on Earth to go skiing.

Comment: I thought this came up yesterday?

Comment: yes, but I was looking for the specific speech term, like aside vs, parenthetical vs. "putting words in someone's mouth: I am not sure if there is a formal speech term of what I did? paraphrasing perhaps? I don't know now

Comment: Completing someone else’s sentence. I know of no formal term.

Comment: I don't know a term for that. But if you want to provide that information to listeners in a way that makes it clear it's not your opinion you could instead make it more of a question: "For skiing?"